pino won't print debug level logs in the console
I am trying to display DEBUG level logs in my React application but none of them are being printed. There's no issue with any other levels, only DEBUG.
I am using pino v9.2.0 and React 18.2.0.
Here's my config:
const send = (level, logEvent) => sendLogToBackend(logEvent);

export const logger = pino({
  level: 'debug',
  browser: {
    serialize: true,
    transmit: {
      send,
    }
  },
  transport: {
    targets: [{
      target : 'pino-pretty',
      level: 'debug'
    }]
  }
});

console.log('########################');
logger.trace('TRACE LOG');
logger.debug('DEBUG LOG');
logger.info('INFO LOG');
logger.warn('WARN LOG');
logger.error('ERROR LOG');
logger.fatal('FATAL LOG');
console.log('########################');


And this is the output:



The send method is used to send the logs to the backend, which surprisingly WORKS with DEBUG level too.

What I tried:

Changed the global level to trace/debug
The transport level to trace/debug
Changed the level to 20 (which should be DEBUG)

EDIT:
Setting verbose to on fixes the issue...


Why is then TRACE shown and DEBUG not, if verbose is disabled?

any fix on this ? I have the same issue ?

Check my EDIT in the questions. I haven't tried anything else as it was enough for my use case.
